# SPOJ Can you answer these queries I

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem on [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GSS1/). I found this problem in the segment tree section, so I am pretty sure that there could be some possible solution that uses segment tree. But I am unable to come up with the metadata that should be stored in the tree node. The maximum sum can be computed using [Kadane's Algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). But how to compute that using segment tree. If we store just the output of algo for a range that would be correct for query for that particular range, but would be incorrect for parents to use that value. If we store some more information like negative sum prefix as well as negative sum suffix. I am able to solve some of the test cases. But its not completely correct. Please provide me some pointers as to how should I approach the metadata for solving this particular problem.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by building a segment tree on the prefix sums

```
sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + a[i]
```

and then keeping the following information in a node:

```
node.min   = the minimum sum[i], x <= i <= y 
            ([x, y] being the interval associated to node)
           = minimum(node.left.min, node.right.min)
node.max   = same but with maximum

node.best  = maximum(node.left.best,
                     node.right.best,
                     node.right.max - node.left.min
                    )
```

Basically, the `best` field gives you the sum of the maximum sum subarray in the associated interval. This is either one of the maximum sum subarrays in the two child nodes, or a sequence that crosses both of the child intervals, which is obtained by subtracting the minimum in the left child from the maximum in the right child, which we also do in a possible linear solution: find the minimum `sum[j], j < i` for each each `i`, then compare `sum[i] - sum[j]` with the global max.

Now, to answer a query you will need to consider the nodes whose associated intervals make up your queried interval and do something similar to how we built the tree. You should try to figure it out on your own, but let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please explain a bit how this logic works. How does best computation you mentioned works?

Comment: @gaurav - just as I described it, you execute those operations after the recursive calls. The values in the leaf nodes are the respective elements in the `sum` array for all 3 fields. Then after the two recursive calls, you do what I described.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I am more interested in how you thought through this logic? Don't you think this is bit unintuitive? I don't understand why max and min would be used? Why not use a prefix negative sum and suffix negative sum. Also for a node's best how could you form a sum out of max-min? If we have a case of 2 elements -10, 1 node.right.max = 1 and node.left.min = -10 in that case best is 11 but making that sum is not possible.

Comment: Maybe I am not trying hard to understand. I am going through the logic once again to be sure.

Comment: @gaurav - remember that you are building the segment tree on the prefix sums array, NOT on the original array. So for `-10, 1` you would build the tree for `-10, -10+1=-9`. In this case, we'd have `-9-(-10)=1`, which is doable, and also the best you can get.

Comment: @gaurav - as for the logic not being intuitive, well, it's not a trivial problem. I thought about how I would solve it in `O(n)` for a single query: there's Kadane's algorithm, but there is also one that uses prefix sums. If you keep the current minimum in the prefix sums array, you can find the maximum subarray that ends at each `i` in `O(1)` like I said in my answer. This led me to this segment tree solution, the only trick was figuring out how to use already-computed intervals, which wasn't that hard since I was familiar with the linear solution.