# find min element over multiple intervals in an array in better than O(N*M) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have three arrays: A, B, C. Corresponding indices of B and C give me the interval to search in A.
example: B[0] = 1, C[0] = 7 so search from indices 1 to 7 in A (inclusive).

I need to find the min of each interval in A and return that as an int array. I think the solution I've come up with runs in O(N*M) where N is the size of array A and M is the size of B and C. I loop through each interval in A and find the min.

Does anyone know how to improve the solution to O(N+M)?

Note: The website says the problem can be solved in O(N+M) time (codility.com). I'm not just guessing. It's also from a section on prefix sums, but I haven't been able to come up with a way to use them for better than O(N*M) solution. A is not sorted.

Comment: If you first sort A (and move the corresponding elements in both B and C) then you can do it in O(n log n + m)

Comment: Do you know for a fact it is possible to do in O(N+M) or are you guessing?

Comment: it is possible. i'm doing some algorithm practice and that is the target time complexity for the "extra challenge". It is from the section on prefix sums if that helps.

Comment: this has to have something to do with overlapping ranges and not re-computing the minimum for a (sub)range you've already seen

Comment: Dynamic programming can help you achieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPOJ Can you answer these queries I](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622157/spoj-can-you-answer-these-queries-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very thin layer over the [range minimum query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) problem. For the best schemes, with O(N) preprocessing, it is possible to answer queries in time O(1), but the implementation is rather complicated. TopCoder hosts a [nice tutorial by danielp](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Range_Minimum_Query_%28RMQ%29) if you want to try.

Comment: Unless im missing something he gave there an O(n*sqrt(n)) solution didnt he?

Comment: @tomer.z The (asymptotically) fastest algorithm is all the way at the end. It uses a bunch of the others as building blocks.

Comment: what does <O(N), O(logN)> mean? N preprocessing and log(n) per query?

Comment: @tomer.z Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1 for large alphabet

You can precompute the minimum of A[i:i+2**k] for every value of i and k up to ceil(log(N)).

This requires O( N log(N) ) preprocessing and O( N log(N) ) storage.

It is then possible to answer each query in O(1) for a total complexity of O( Nlog(N)+M ).

For example, to find the minimum of A[2:13] you can find the minimum of the precomputed results for A[2:2+2**3] and A[5:5+2**3]

### Solution 2 for small alphabet

If the number of distinct elements in A is small and fixed e.g. 10, then you can do this in O(N+M) using prefix sums.

Simply compute a prefix sum for each distinct element e P[e][i] that counts the number of occurrences of e for indices <= i.  Then for each query you can determine whether a particular element is present in that range via a simple subtraction for each element type.

This requires O(KN) preprocessing and O(KM) query time where K is the number of distinct elements in A.

For a fixed K this becomes O(N+M).

Comment: @tomer.z because of the complexity being too high, or have I misunderstood the problem in some other way?

Comment: Complexity is too high, he asked for O(N+M)

Answer (score 2):

After four years, and no one answered this question.

I solved [this question](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/) using a matrix that with four columns (1 for each nucleotide's type), adding one each time that nucleotide appears on the sequence.

So, that way, you can calculate if each one of the nucleotide types appears on that interval.

Remember that O(4*n) becomes O(n), and O(m+n) is the same as O(m+4n).

Comment: Were you meaning to answer a different question? I don't see how this is related to the question here...

Comment: Hey @CrisLuengo, did you follow the link? The problem I linked is to find a minimum value in a string (that can be seen as an array of characters) and the range is defined by the arrays P and Q. In this question, there are 4 possible different values, so that's why I posted that I used a matrix with 4 columns.

Comment: I don't see in this question that there is a limited set of possible input values. If that were the case, then yes, your approach is useful.

Comment: Well, the original author didn't post a link to the question he was referring, but I think it is very similar to this one that I put the link. Don't you think, @CrisLuengo?

Comment: @MarcioBueno - the author of the question has mentioned codility.com and the question seems to be the one that you are referring to, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.